# How to split an image into 12 different custom shape in unity3D or c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing game in which I choose picture from the gallery and then what I need to do is cut it into 12 custom shape part which will be used then as a puzzle I need those 12 piece to merge together and create the same.

Edit: To those who don't understand the question what i'm trying to accomplish is trying to split an single image into different part and then player will figure out the sequence of part and make the image.
I want the player to add the picture from his/her collection to make it more challenging and challenge others player.
A picture will make it more clear but as I don't have enough credit and i'm getting -ve one in this i don't know how to put it more clearly in the reader mind.

Answer (score 1):

A possiblilty for which you are looking for is [masking feature](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html) of UI components. You can deal with the flag `Show mask graphics` to show/hide the relative parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Graphics.DrawImage` to draw a cropped image onto the graphics object from a bitmap.

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(...);
Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
   g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), 
                    cropRect,                        
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but the problem is I don't want to make rectangle type shape. shapes are different for each cell of puzzle so How can i accomplish that.